# repo sync permission denied, on a code that I copied from someone else

Tags: git, repo

I copied code from colleague, and then tried to repo sync again. But I am getting permission denied error. How can I avoid this issue? I know there were lot of answers in regards to adding ssh keys, but nothing related to this...Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you copied `.repo` under the code root directory too. Enter `.repo/manifests` and run `git remote -v` to check the url of `origin`. If it's an ssh url, there should be a username in it. The username is your colleague's. You can't use this url to sync the code unless you add your current key to his/her user settings of the host server.

You can run `repo init -u <url_with_your_username_to_manifest_repository> -b <manifest_branch> -m <manifest_name>` to re-initialize the code repo and then run `repo sync` again.

If it still complains about permission denied, then you'll have to check if your username has access rights to the repositories in the host server.

Comment: Thank you so much, I will give it a try. One more thing...in the same sense...how can I change edk2 tool path to my path?